# Why not two Blood Jars in The Last Apprentice?

Tags: novel, magic, wardstone-chronicles

At the end of book 6, "The Clash of the Demons" of The Last Apprentice (aka "The Spook's Sacrifice" of the Wardstone Chronicles), Thomas Ward was about to sell his soul to the Fiend when Alice came and placed a blood jar in his hand, sending the Fiend away. Now she must keep close to Tom, or the Fiend will take his revenge upon her.

But why don't they make *two* blood jars? That way Alice would be able to go as far away from Tom when the need came.

Comment: Not sure what to tag this as... Maybe someone could make the "last-apprentice" tag?

Comment: I retagged, are these tags good for you?

Comment: @Mark Yeah. :) But "the-clash-of-the-demons" might be overdoing it.

Comment: Because the novels are published (natively) in the UK as the Wardstone Chronicles, I suggest adding tags of both "last-apprentice" and "wardstone-chronicles."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 427 of book 7, *Rise of the Huntress*, by Joseph Delaney:

> "What if I were to smash this [the
>   blood jar] now, or drain it of its
>   contents?" he asked me. "Could the
>   girl [Alice] make another?"
>
> "Ain't possible to make another to
>   save Tom," said Alice. "You can only
>   use a spell like that once."